# Dynamic GatsbyJS + Node Express deployment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cpanel, gatsby

I have a GatsbyJS app to which I added a dynamic side, starting with a contact form using Axios which on POST calls the Express server and sends an email.

Everything is now working locally, but I am having trouble moving to my provider as I am new to backend technology.

Locally, I followed https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/client-only-routes-and-user-authentication/ and added the server as a proxy in the package configuration. My host is using cPanel which allows configuring a NodeJS app, which I tried and setup the app but I cannot make it work properly with the front

```
gatsby-node.js

exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  // Only update the `/app` page.
  if (page.path.match(/^\/app/)) {
    // page.matchPath is a special key that's used for matching pages
    // with corresponding routes only on the client.
    page.matchPath = "/app/*"

    // Update the page.
    createPage(page)
  }
}
```

```
ContactForm.js

 const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://websiteaddress.com/post",
      data: { name: name, email: email, message: message },
    }).then (...)
```

```
app.js

const Router = () => {
  return (
    <MyRouter basepath="/more">
      <ContactForm path="/contact" />
    </MyRouter>
  )
}
```

server.js is basically using nodemailer and working fine on localhost

My current online Node + static files uploaded to the server render only the static part (the form is not rendered). The Node app is running

How to adapt the configuration (for example the `"proxy": "http://localhost:3000"` which worked locally) to make it behave on the host as it should?

Comment: YOu must add a proxy to package.json

Comment: I already have, it is working locally but the uploaded version is not. Can you please provide more info/code examples?

Comment: Do you have any errors to show?

Comment: Well so far I haven't been able to even render the dynamic route with the contact form on the server, so no errors to debug. Everything static is working on its own, and the NodeJS app from cPanel seems to be running independently

Comment: I think that express server need's so serve that gatsby site. You can use this: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-express/